# Transfer Java Map.Entry to Stream with Non-final Variables

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Actually this is LeetCode #56 where I use a TreeMap for compute the results.

The codes are:

```
public List<Interval> merge(List<Interval> intervals) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> tMap = intervals.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i.start, i -> i.end, (i, j) -> i > j ? i : j));
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer> (tMap);
    List<Interval> res = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE, right = Integer.MAX_VALUE, tmpLeft = -1, tmpRight = -1;
    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : set)
    {
        if (Integer.MAX_VALUE == left && Integer.MAX_VALUE == right)
        {
            left = entry.getKey();
            right = entry.getValue();
        }
        else
        {
            tmpLeft = entry.getKey();
            tmpRight = entry.getValue();
            if(right < tmpLeft)
            {
                res.add(new Interval(left, right));
                left = tmpLeft;
            }
            right = right > tmpRight ? right : tmpRight;
        }
    }
    if (Integer.MAX_VALUE != left && Integer.MAX_VALUE != right)
        res.add(new Interval(left, right));
    return res;
}
```

Although it works, I'm wondering if there's a way for doing this in stream.

1. Can TreeMap `Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer> (tMap);` be directly generated by stream?
2. When I have the `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> set` and the following for loop, is there some way to do it in stream?

Comment: `(i, j) -> i > j ? i : j` is the same as `Math::max`

Answer (score 1):

1- Use the `toMap` collector method which accepts also a `Supplier<M>`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> tMap = intervals.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i.start, i -> i.end, (i, j) -> i > j ? i : j), () -> new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>());
```

2- You can replace:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : set)
{ ...
```

With:

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> { ...
```

But I think it does not worth it.

Comment: There's also `map.forEach((key, value) -> { ... });` which is a better option than an entry-set stream.

Comment: `() -> new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>()` can be replaced by either `() -> new TreeMap<>()` or even `TreeMap::new`. Besides that, you can’t replace the loop with a `forEach`, as it modifies local variables declared outside the loop.

Comment: Your way using lambda for making the map to a tree map is really smart! But I'm not sure about the 2nd one since I modify `tmpLeft` and `tmpRight` which is not final. But thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `TreeMap` creation to

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = intervals.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i.start, i -> i.end, Math::max, TreeMap::new));
```

but actually, the `TreeMap` is only a kludge for getting the interval data sorted by their starting point. While a `TreeMap` is sufficient if you really need a sorted storage, it isn’t the most efficient solution for a one-time sorting.

You may use:

```
intervals = intervals.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.start))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE, right = Integer.MAX_VALUE, tmpLeft = -1, tmpRight = -1;
 // proceed with your loop as before,
 // using i.start and i.end instead of entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
for(Interval i: intervals)
{
    …
```

though, it might be more efficient to use the Collection API here:

```
intervals = new ArrayList<>(intervals);
intervals.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.start));
int left = Integer.MAX_VALUE, right = Integer.MAX_VALUE, tmpLeft = -1, tmpRight = -1;
 // proceed with your loop as before,
 // using i.start and i.end instead of entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
for(Interval i: intervals)
{
    …
```

In both cases, a new list is created, assuming that you don’t want to modify the parameter list and to be independent of implementation details of that list.

The loop’s logic can be expressed as a stream operation, but it wouldn’t be simpler as the loop. You would need a custom collector bearing almost the same operation you’re doing in the loop now, plus a merge function which does a similar thing for two lists, to support parallel operations.

Comment: Thank you Holger for the answer. I asked about stream and lambda because recently I was reading the book "Java Functional Programming" and wanted to try. But this is really a good solution! Thank you very much!